# Vue 3 - access to children components (form validation)

Tags: typescript, vuejs3

I am trying to achieve some kind of form validations with my own components

- MyForm
- MyInput
- MySelect
- ...

Every field component such as MyInput, MySelect, exposes `validate()` method

What I am trying to do

screenWithForm.vue

```
<template>
  <MyForm ...>
    <MyInput ... />

    <div>
      <MySelect ... />
    </div>

    <template name="button">
      <div>Send form</div>
  </MyForm>
</template>
```

MyForm.vue

```
<script lang="ts" setup>
const submitForm = () => {
    //here I need to go through all MyInput, MySelect components and call `validate()` method and then do some emits
}
</script>

<template>
    <slot />

    <div @click="submitForm()">
        <slot name="button" />
    </div>
</template>
```

So the purpose of MyForm wrapper should be to check all children elements, call `validate()` to show errors or emit some event when is valid.

I was trying use `$refs` which is not possible to use the same ref for multiple elements and get array of elements (which I expected). Maybe the solutions could be by using `useSlots()` but I've also tried lot of approaches and still can't find the correct solution.

I am just looking for some equivalent to Angular `@ViewChildren` directive

Comment: Did you try an approach with `v-model`? I think, your parent element should bind a state for each child to a vModel and then validate it and pass an error state to the fields. In this case, you can define different validations for the fields and make your inputs more reusable

Comment: Probably don't understand. because each MyInput, MySelect, etc has vModel itself, so what I am trying to do, is basically when user clicks to some submit button, then go through all the children inputs and call validate() to show all errir messages within the inputs itself.